# Kafka 10.1.1 brokers hang when one of the brokers is killed manullay in three node cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We have three node Kafka Cluster. If we killed one of node from cluster remaining two nodes are not consuming the data. it hang.

we are getting below message at consumer console:

```
WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-consumer-26249: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

We have tried with below properties. But no use.

```
enble.auto.commit = true

auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000

offsets.commit.timeout.ms=50000 @ server.properties at each brokers
```

Env: 0.10.1.1 and linux machine

If we bring up the service whichever we made it killed then all are trying consuming data automatically.

Kindly help us what is the problem